# Alphabetical ordering of last names in Bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

In the latex file given below, I will like to sort references in alphabetical order of the last names (of first author.) Presently, the references are cited as numbers, where the first mentioned citation is assigned number 1 in Bibliography, the second mentioned citation is assigned number 2 and so on. The picture given below shows how the ordering is presently.

[image]

I will like the assignment of numbers to references in Bibliography (and text in different sections) to be on the basis of **alphabetical order of the last names (of first author.)** In the above given example the order should be `1.> L Amendola et al., 2.> A Einstein, 3.> S Perlmutter`. How can I do that?

This is my `tex` file.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{latexclass}
\usepackage[style=numeric-comp, sorting=none, backend=bibtex, doi=false, isbn=false, natbib=true]{biblatex}
\makeatletter
\def\blx@maxline{77}
\makeatother

\newcommand*{\bibtitle}{References}

\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\raggedright\small}

\addbibresource{ref.bib}

\providecommand\apj{The Astrophysical Journal}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2009}{\,} 
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2212}{\,} 
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{223C}{\,} 

\begin{document}

\section{Section}
Cite \cite{Perlmutter1999, Amendola2017, Einstein1915}

{\renewcommand*\MakeUppercase[1]{#1}%
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,title={\bibtitle}]}

\end{document}
```

Here is my `cls` file (`latexclass.cls`)

```
\LoadClass[openright,12pt]{report}

\newif\ifmc@nobind
\mc@nobindfalse

\DeclareOption{nobind}{\mc@nobindtrue}
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{report}}
\ProcessOptions\relax

\ifmc@nobind

\usepackage[sort]{natbib} 

\usepackage[biblabels]{authorindex} 

\usepackage[includehead,hmargin={3.1cm, 3.1cm}, vmargin={2.5cm,2.7cm}, headsep=.8cm,footskip=1.2cm]{geometry}
\else
\usepackage[includehead,hmargin={3.6cm, 2.6cm}, vmargin={2.5cm,2.7cm}, headsep=.8cm,footskip=1.2cm]{geometry}
\fi

\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{longtable} 
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption} 
\usepackage{multicol,multirow,array} 
\usepackage{rotating} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{pdfpages} 
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[3]{D{.}{\cdot}{#1} } 
\usepackage{notoccite} 
\usepackage[colorlinks=false,pdfpagelabels]{hyperref} 
\usepackage[nohints,tight]{minitoc} 
    \setcounter{minitocdepth}{2} 
\let\oldmtc@verse\mtc@verse
\renewcommand{\mtc@verse}[1]{\oldmtc@verse{#1}\setlength{\baselineskip}{\z@}}

\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}

\let\@ldtoc\tableofcontents
\renewcommand*\tableofcontents{{%
\renewcommand*\MakeUppercase[1]{##1}\@ldtoc}}
\let\@ldlof\listoffigures
\renewcommand*\listoffigures{{%
\renewcommand*\MakeUppercase[1]{##1}\@ldlof}}
\let\@ldlot\listoftables
\renewcommand*\listoftables{{%
\renewcommand*\MakeUppercase[1]{##1}\@ldlot}}
\let\@ldbib\bibliography
\renewcommand*\bibliography[1]{{%
\renewcommand*\MakeUppercase[1]{##1}\@ldbib{#1}}}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[LGR,TS1,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek,latin,english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\hyphenpenalty=500
\def\longs{{\fontencoding{TS1}\selectfont s}}

\colorlet{shadecolor}{blue!20}
```

And here is my `bib` file (`ref.bib`)

```
@ARTICLE{Amendola2017,
   author = {{Amendola}, L. and {Kunz}, M. and {Saltas}, I.~D. and {Sawicki}, I.},
title = "{The fate of large-scale structure in modified gravity after GW170817 and GRB170817A}",
  journal = {ArXiv e-prints},
 archivePrefix = "arXiv",
  eprint = {1711.04825},
 keywords = {Astrophysics - Cosmology and Nongalactic Astrophysics, General Relativity and Quantum Cosmology, High Energy Physics - Theory},
   year = 2017,
   month = nov,
   adsurl = {http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2017arXiv171104825A},
  adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System}
}


@article{Einstein1915,
 title = "The Field Equations of Gravitation",
journal = "Preussische Akademie der Wissenschaften, Sitzungsberichte",
volume = "844",
number = "7",
pages = "117 - 137",
year = "1915",
url = "http://einsteinpapers.press.princeton.edu/vol6-trans/129",
author = "A. Einstein"
 }

@ARTICLE{Perlmutter1999,
   author = {{Perlmutter}, S. and {Aldering}, G. and {Goldhaber}, G. and 
{Knop}, R.~A. and {Nugent}, P. and {Castro}, P.~G. and {Deustua}, S. and 
{Fabbro}, S. and {Goobar}, A. and {Groom}, D.~E. and {Hook}, I.~M. and 
{Kim}, A.~G. and {Kim}, M.~Y. and {Lee}, J.~C. and {Nunes}, N.~J. and 
{Pain}, R. and {Pennypacker}, C.~R. and {Quimby}, R. and {Lidman}, C. and 
{Ellis}, R.~S. and {Irwin}, M. and {McMahon}, R.~G. and {Ruiz-Lapuente}, P. and 
{Walton}, N. and {Schaefer}, B. and {Boyle}, B.~J. and {Filippenko}, A.~V. and 
{Matheson}, T. and {Fruchter}, A.~S. and {Panagia}, N. and {Newberg}, H.~J.~M. and 
{Couch}, W.~J. and {Project}, T.~S.~C.},
    title = "{Measurements of {$\Omega$} and {$\Lambda$} from 42 High-Redshift Supernovae}",
    journal = {\apj},
   eprint = {astro-ph/9812133},
 keywords = {COSMOLOGY: OBSERVATIONS, COSMOLOGY: DISTANCE SCALE, STARS: SUPERNOVAE: GENERAL, Cosmology: Observations, Cosmology: Distance Scale, Stars: Supernovae: General},
    year = 1999,
    month = jun,
   volume = 517,
    pages = {565-586},
     doi = {10.1086/307221},
  adsurl = {http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1999ApJ...517..565P},
  adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've set biblatex with option `sorting=none`. That will give you references sorted by citation order. If you want them sorted by alphabetical order of the first author, you should use `nyt` (name, year, title) or `nty` (name, title, year). But, as `nyt` is already the default, you just need to omit `sorting=none` from your biblatex's options.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[style=numeric-comp, backend=bibtex, doi=false, isbn=false, natbib=true]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{Amendola2017,
  author = {{Amendola}, L. and {Kunz}, M. and {Saltas}, I.~D. and {Sawicki}, I.},
  title = "{The fate of large-scale structure in modified gravity after GW170817 and GRB170817A}",
  journal = {ArXiv e-prints},
  archivePrefix = "arXiv",
  eprint = {1711.04825},
  keywords = {Astrophysics - Cosmology and Nongalactic Astrophysics, General Relativity and Quantum Cosmology, High Energy Physics - Theory},
  year = 2017,
  month = nov,
  adsurl = {http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2017arXiv171104825A},
  adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System}
}


@article{Einstein1915,
  title = "The Field Equations of Gravitation",
  journal = "Preussische Akademie der Wissenschaften, Sitzungsberichte",
  volume = "844",
  number = "7",
  pages = "117 - 137",
  year = "1915",
  url = "http://einsteinpapers.press.princeton.edu/vol6-trans/129",
  author = "A. Einstein"
 }

@ARTICLE{Perlmutter1999,
  author = {{Perlmutter}, S. and {Aldering}, G. and {Goldhaber}, G. and
{Knop}, R.~A. and {Nugent}, P. and {Castro}, P.~G. and {Deustua}, S. and
{Fabbro}, S. and {Goobar}, A. and {Groom}, D.~E. and {Hook}, I.~M. and
{Kim}, A.~G. and {Kim}, M.~Y. and {Lee}, J.~C. and {Nunes}, N.~J. and
{Pain}, R. and {Pennypacker}, C.~R. and {Quimby}, R. and {Lidman}, C. and
{Ellis}, R.~S. and {Irwin}, M. and {McMahon}, R.~G. and {Ruiz-Lapuente}, P. and
{Walton}, N. and {Schaefer}, B. and {Boyle}, B.~J. and {Filippenko}, A.~V. and
{Matheson}, T. and {Fruchter}, A.~S. and {Panagia}, N. and {Newberg}, H.~J.~M. and
{Couch}, W.~J. and {Project}, T.~S.~C.},
  title = "{Measurements of {$\Omega$} and {$\Lambda$} from 42 High-Redshift Supernovae}",
  journal = {The Astrophysical Journal},
  eprint = {astro-ph/9812133},
  keywords = {COSMOLOGY: OBSERVATIONS, COSMOLOGY: DISTANCE SCALE, STARS: SUPERNOVAE: GENERAL, Cosmology: Observations, Cosmology: Distance Scale, Stars: Supernovae: General},
  year = 1999,
  month = jun,
  volume = 517,
  pages = {565-586},
  doi = {10.1086/307221},
  adsurl = {http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1999ApJ...517..565P},
  adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\newcommand*{\bibtitle}{References}

\begin{document}

\section{Section}
Cite \cite{Perlmutter1999, Amendola2017, Einstein1915}

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,title={\bibtitle}]

\end{document}
```

[image]